# Modify textView in a fragment from MainActivity using SharedPreferences (Kotlin)

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-activity, fragment

I have an issue with a project in Kotlin. I need to modify textViews in fragments but I cannot access those textView.
The error I receive back is:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.example/com.example.example.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: emailSettingsText must not be null
```

In my MainActivity (where the fragment is) I tried this:

```
emailSettingsText.text = sharedPreferences.getString("EMAIL", "")
```

I tried also to create a var in my main activity:

```
var = emailVar = sharedPreferences.getString("EMAIL", "")
```

but I cannot change the text in the fragment.

This is the fragment:

```
package com.example.example.ui.settings

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders
import com.example.example.R
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_terms.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_settings.*


@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
class SettingsFragment : Fragment() {


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?

    ): View? {

        ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SettingsViewModel::class.java)




        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false)
    }
```

}

Is there any way to change a textView called emailShowSettingsText in the fragment?
Thank u for any help.

This is my activity code:

```
package com.example.example

import android.content.Context
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.Settings
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.TextView
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import com.example.example.ui.settings.SettingsFragment
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_settings.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_settings.view.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_traffic.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), Communicator {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)

        val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("TOKEN_FILE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)

        var dominioVal = sharedPreferences.getString("DOMINIO", "")

        AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.navigation_traffic, R.id.navigation_ipblocked, R.id.navigation_search_terms, R.id.navigation_settings
            )
        )

        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you post your activity code?

Comment: Thank u for the reply! I've added my activity code too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I solved the problem using companion objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_terms.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_settings.*
```

You import 2 synthetic xml files in a Activity, something wrong here,

Seem like `emailSettingsText` belong to Fragment but you tried to call it in Activity.

You only able to control a view via synthetic if your Fragment or your Activity reference to its xml file (setContentView in Activity or inflate layout in fragment)

```
emailSettingsText.text = sharedPreferences.getString("EMAIL", "")
```

I think the problem will be solve if you move the line of code above to`onViewCreated` of Fragment

Comment: Thank u for the answer! I will try and I will text to you if it works!

Answer (score 0):

It's no problem you call id TextView "emailSettingsText" from the fragment in your main activity. But, you have to check 2 things :

1. Set your fragment in your activity using "FragmentTransaction". You can use this code.

```
fun setFragment(fragmentManager: FragmentManager, fragmentString: String, fragment: Fragment, layout_fragment: Int) {
   val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
   fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentString)
   fragmentTransaction.add(layout_fragment, fragment, fragmentString)
   fragmentTransaction.commit()
}
```

2. Checking your id TextView in your fragment.

I checked your code on "MainActivity". You haven't set your fragment in the activity. Maybe that's what caused you to get an error like that.